# Room entry/exit detection using iBeacon RSSI

Tags: android, ibeacon, rssi

I'm detecting if a person enters or exits a room using iBeacon. The implementation is as follows:
1. Two beacons are placed per room. One in the door and the other is inside near the door. 
2. To detect entry, the user must pass the door beacon then the one inside the room. For exit, it's the other way around.

Issue: 
In case that there are rooms that are too adjacent with each other, an overlap will occur causing an error in the detection

Planned Solution: 
Use RSSI to detect which one is the last nearest beacon when the inside room is detected. I'm thinking of checking the skewness of the distribution of the RSSI on a given time, say around 1 to 2 seconds since the user detected an inside beacon.

Is there other statistical analysis or any data analysis that can be used to determine or check with a probability which room the user entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the rooms are very large (which it sounds like they are not based on the troubles you are having) I think any technique you find will have a high error rate.  You might be able to get this error rate down far enough to be acceptable by recognizing cases where you simply cannot make a determination and refusing to do so in these cases to avoid false determinations.

Your best bet is to sample multiple RSSI measurements from different beacon packets (a minimum of 10 to filter out noise), then average them, perhaps throwing out the highest and lowest value before doing so. If this average RSSI is strong enough, say < -80 dB (and it is the strongest signal you have seen from all beacons) there is a high probability you are in the room indicated by the beacon.

The RSSI may drop off if you go far away from the beacon in the room so just because the criteria above are not met does not mean you are not in the room.

Keep in mind that it is impossible to determine which beacon is closest if all signals are weak -- noise becomes more important than signal.  So make no conclusions unless one beacon has RSSI stronger than, say -85 dBm.

Make sure your beacons are transmitting as strongly as possible and advertising as often as possible.  The latter will ensure that you get enough RSSI samples in a short time.

Finally, keep in mind that different Android phones have different Bluetooth antennas and  receive the same beacon packets more or less strongly.  A Huawei P9 Lite detects BLE signals at an RSSI 20 dB weaker than a similarly placed  Moto G4+.  Regardless of this, phones typically do not detect beacon signals weaker that -100 dBm and below -90 dBm the measurement is so weak as to become almost useless for relative distance determination.

Comment: It seems that this kind of setup produces a very high error rate.
I ended up placing a door beacon near the door knob for ranging and an inside beacon for monitoring. Thanks!